# pandas How to handle date change while merging/joining 2 DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have following to DataFrames and I am using merge to combine to columns as follows:

df1 contains login/logout times

```
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| P_Id  |    Date    |           LoginTime           |          LogoutTime           |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 10830 | 2019-11-13 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 10830 | 2019-11-14 | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 10830 | 2019-11-15 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 10830 | 2019-11-16 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
| 10830 | 2019-11-17 | 2019-11-17 14:18:20.549867100 | 2019-11-18 01:38:23.505849200 |
+-------+------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

df2 contains time of events that happened between one login and logout.

```
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+
|  Id  |             Start             | P_Id  |              End              | Month |    Date    | Day | Week_day | Hour |           After           |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+
| 5190 | 2019-11-13 16:00:46.355864100 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:01:52.214816300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 |                           |
| 5191 | 2019-11-13 16:02:24.726404400 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:03:02.068703500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:32.511588100 |
| 5193 | 2019-11-13 16:03:57.336799800 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:06:52.735558300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:55.268096300 |
| 5194 | 2019-11-13 16:08:50.803699400 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:11:31.797923600 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:01:58.068141100 |
| 5198 | 2019-11-13 16:51:03.613695300 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 17:28:38.597633100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   17 | 0 days 00:39:31.815771700 |
| 5200 | 2019-11-13 17:30:35.305265600 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 18:09:20.454238200 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   18 | 0 days 00:01:56.707632500 |
| 5211 | 2019-11-13 22:14:37.616688600 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 22:17:27.129620500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 04:05:17.162450400 |
| 5214 | 2019-11-13 22:44:01.224241000 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 22:59:39.863998100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 00:26:34.094620500 |
| 5256 | 2019-11-14 23:21:33.186943200 | 10830 | 2019-11-14 23:56:16.082169100 |    11 | 2019-11-14 |  14 |        3 |   23 |                           |
| 5258 | 2019-11-15 00:24:57.483800900 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 00:31:47.959459400 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 |                           |
| 5259 | 2019-11-15 00:33:50.642483100 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 00:49:09.138852000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 | 0 days 00:02:02.683023700 |
| 5261 | 2019-11-15 01:44:44.293864600 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 01:59:07.159142200 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    1 | 0 days 00:55:35.155012600 |
| 5263 | 2019-11-15 02:05:33.623635000 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 02:12:15.581544000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    2 | 0 days 00:06:26.464492800 |
| 5286 | 2019-11-15 17:54:30.140008300 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 18:53:40.433555800 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   18 | 0 days 15:42:14.558464300 |
| 5296 | 2019-11-15 20:57:29.508330200 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 21:02:44.851496700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 02:03:49.074774400 |
| 5297 | 2019-11-15 21:22:24.220020000 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 21:35:19.343132000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 00:19:39.368523300 |
| 5300 | 2019-11-15 21:57:41.880812100 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 22:15:32.520381000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   22 | 0 days 00:22:22.537680100 |
| 5301 | 2019-11-15 23:00:03.505284200 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 23:15:31.295551700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:44:30.984903200 |
| 5302 | 2019-11-15 23:17:00.816945700 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 23:29:21.781482300 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:01:29.521394000 |
| 5303 | 2019-11-15 23:45:16.858411100 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:09:29.816557900 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 |                           |
|      | 2019-11-16 00:27:19.138782200 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:42:06.387264200 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:17:49.322224300 |
|      | 2019-11-16 00:57:33.712924800 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:58:06.315696400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:15:27.325660600 |
|      | 2019-11-16 01:09:55.180647700 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 01:15:08.916555400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    1 | 0 days 00:11:48.864951300 |
|      | 2019-11-16 18:04:30.656633300 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 19:12:32.382217300 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |   19 | 0 days 16:49:21.740077900 |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+
```

For time difference calculation purposes I wanted to merge them(calculating time differences among events within a single login and logout) so that logout and login times can be added as columns next to the df2 so i used

```
m=pd.merge(gf, df, how ='inner', on=['DriverId', 'Month', 'Date']) // calculated Month and Date for df1 as well
```

This gives me following output:

```
+------+------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  Id  | P_Id |             Start             | DriverId |              End              | Month |    Date    | Day | Week_day | Hour |             f             |           LoginTime           |          LogoutTime           |
+------+------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 5190 |      | 2019-11-13 16:00:46.355864100 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 16:01:52.214816300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 |                           | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5191 |      | 2019-11-13 16:02:24.726404400 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 16:03:02.068703500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:32.511588100 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5193 |      | 2019-11-13 16:03:57.336799800 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 16:06:52.735558300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:55.268096300 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5194 | 2489 | 2019-11-13 16:08:50.803699400 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 16:11:31.797923600 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:01:58.068141100 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5198 | 2492 | 2019-11-13 16:51:03.613695300 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 17:28:38.597633100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   17 | 0 days 00:39:31.815771700 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5200 | 2494 | 2019-11-13 17:30:35.305265600 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 18:09:20.454238200 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   18 | 0 days 00:01:56.707632500 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5211 | 2504 | 2019-11-13 22:14:37.616688600 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 22:17:27.129620500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 04:05:17.162450400 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5214 |      | 2019-11-13 22:44:01.224241000 |    10830 | 2019-11-13 22:59:39.863998100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 00:26:34.094620500 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5256 |      | 2019-11-14 23:21:33.186943200 |    10830 | 2019-11-14 23:56:16.082169100 |    11 | 2019-11-14 |  14 |        3 |   23 |                           | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5258 |      | 2019-11-15 00:24:57.483800900 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 00:31:47.959459400 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 |                           | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5259 |      | 2019-11-15 00:33:50.642483100 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 00:49:09.138852000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 | 0 days 00:02:02.683023700 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5261 |      | 2019-11-15 01:44:44.293864600 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 01:59:07.159142200 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    1 | 0 days 00:55:35.155012600 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5263 |      | 2019-11-15 02:05:33.623635000 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 02:12:15.581544000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    2 | 0 days 00:06:26.464492800 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5286 | 2543 | 2019-11-15 17:54:30.140008300 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 18:53:40.433555800 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   18 | 0 days 15:42:14.558464300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5296 |      | 2019-11-15 20:57:29.508330200 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 21:02:44.851496700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 02:03:49.074774400 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5297 |      | 2019-11-15 21:22:24.220020000 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 21:35:19.343132000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 00:19:39.368523300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5300 |      | 2019-11-15 21:57:41.880812100 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 22:15:32.520381000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   22 | 0 days 00:22:22.537680100 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5301 |      | 2019-11-15 23:00:03.505284200 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 23:15:31.295551700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:44:30.984903200 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5302 |      | 2019-11-15 23:17:00.816945700 |    10830 | 2019-11-15 23:29:21.781482300 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:01:29.521394000 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5303 |      | 2019-11-15 23:45:16.858411100 |    10830 | 2019-11-16 00:09:29.816557900 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 |                           | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
| 5304 |      | 2019-11-16 00:27:19.138782200 |    10830 | 2019-11-16 00:42:06.387264200 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:17:49.322224300 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
| 5305 |      | 2019-11-16 00:57:33.712924800 |    10830 | 2019-11-16 00:58:06.315696400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:15:27.325660600 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
| 5306 |      | 2019-11-16 01:09:55.180647700 |    10830 | 2019-11-16 01:15:08.916555400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    1 | 0 days 00:11:48.864951300 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
| 5329 |      | 2019-11-16 18:04:30.656633300 |    10830 | 2019-11-16 19:12:32.382217300 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |   19 | 0 days 16:49:21.740077900 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
+------+------+-------------------------------+----------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

but the problem is that for some logons and logout `date` changes and the next login can occur on same date as previous logout as well, I am looking for something like the following.

```
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|  Id  |             Start             | P_Id  |              End              | Month |    Date    | Day | Week_day | Hour |           After           |           LoginTime           |          LogoutTime           |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 5190 | 2019-11-13 16:00:46.355864100 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:01:52.214816300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 |                           | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5191 | 2019-11-13 16:02:24.726404400 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:03:02.068703500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:32.511588100 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5193 | 2019-11-13 16:03:57.336799800 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:06:52.735558300 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:00:55.268096300 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5194 | 2019-11-13 16:08:50.803699400 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 16:11:31.797923600 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   16 | 0 days 00:01:58.068141100 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5198 | 2019-11-13 16:51:03.613695300 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 17:28:38.597633100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   17 | 0 days 00:39:31.815771700 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5200 | 2019-11-13 17:30:35.305265600 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 18:09:20.454238200 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   18 | 0 days 00:01:56.707632500 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5211 | 2019-11-13 22:14:37.616688600 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 22:17:27.129620500 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 04:05:17.162450400 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5214 | 2019-11-13 22:44:01.224241000 | 10830 | 2019-11-13 22:59:39.863998100 |    11 | 2019-11-13 |  13 |        2 |   22 | 0 days 00:26:34.094620500 | 2019-11-13 15:58:44.977126500 | 2019-11-14 00:13:19.111769600 |
| 5256 | 2019-11-14 23:21:33.186943200 | 10830 | 2019-11-14 23:56:16.082169100 |    11 | 2019-11-14 |  14 |        3 |   23 |                           | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5258 | 2019-11-15 00:24:57.483800900 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 00:31:47.959459400 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 |                           | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5259 | 2019-11-15 00:33:50.642483100 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 00:49:09.138852000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    0 | 0 days 00:02:02.683023700 | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5261 | 2019-11-15 01:44:44.293864600 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 01:59:07.159142200 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    1 | 0 days 00:55:35.155012600 | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5263 | 2019-11-15 02:05:33.623635000 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 02:12:15.581544000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |    2 | 0 days 00:06:26.464492800 | 2019-11-14 22:11:02.429253600 | 2019-11-15 03:24:03.297526800 |
| 5286 | 2019-11-15 17:54:30.140008300 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 18:53:40.433555800 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   18 | 0 days 15:42:14.558464300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5296 | 2019-11-15 20:57:29.508330200 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 21:02:44.851496700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 02:03:49.074774400 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5297 | 2019-11-15 21:22:24.220020000 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 21:35:19.343132000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   21 | 0 days 00:19:39.368523300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5300 | 2019-11-15 21:57:41.880812100 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 22:15:32.520381000 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   22 | 0 days 00:22:22.537680100 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5301 | 2019-11-15 23:00:03.505284200 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 23:15:31.295551700 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:44:30.984903200 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5302 | 2019-11-15 23:17:00.816945700 | 10830 | 2019-11-15 23:29:21.781482300 |    11 | 2019-11-15 |  15 |        4 |   23 | 0 days 00:01:29.521394000 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
| 5303 | 2019-11-15 23:45:16.858411100 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:09:29.816557900 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 |                           | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
|      | 2019-11-16 00:27:19.138782200 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:42:06.387264200 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:17:49.322224300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
|      | 2019-11-16 00:57:33.712924800 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 00:58:06.315696400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    0 | 0 days 00:15:27.325660600 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
|      | 2019-11-16 01:09:55.180647700 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 01:15:08.916555400 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |    1 | 0 days 00:11:48.864951300 | 2019-11-15 16:22:50.725217200 | 2019-11-16 01:58:51.869172700 |
|      | 2019-11-16 18:04:30.656633300 | 10830 | 2019-11-16 19:12:32.382217300 |    11 | 2019-11-16 |  16 |        5 |   19 | 0 days 16:49:21.740077900 | 2019-11-16 17:49:44.048717800 | 2019-11-17 01:47:12.073102200 |
+------+-------------------------------+-------+-------------------------------+-------+------------+-----+----------+------+---------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: It is unclear what is wrong with your current code.

Comment: @jorijnsmit I have edited my post and entered the output I am getting.

Comment: So your current output is exactly as expected except for the `Id` column. What goes wrong there? I still cannot understand your problem. Also, how can you merge on `Month` if it is not included in the first dataframe?

Comment: @jorijnsmit sir, you are not reading the question, I have written that 'calculated month and date for df1 as well'

Comment: @jorijnsmit my output is different from desired output you have to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use outer join by `P_Id` column first and then filter matching between columns - if possible multiple match get al of them:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how ='outer', on='P_Id')
df2 = df1[(df1.LogoutTime >= df1.Start) & (df1.LoginTime <= df1.End)]
```